# How to preserve form fields in django after unsuccessful submit?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Code from views.py:

```
def feedback(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print("form.errors:", form.errors)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    articles = Comment.objects.all()
    ResponseDict = {"articles": articles, "form": form}
    return render_to_response("feedback.html", ResponseDict, 
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I've tried this and several modifications from answers to similar questions, but nothing works. When I press submit button, all form fields in html become empty.

EDIT: code from feedback.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main %}
    <table>
        <form action="/feedback/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="article">
                <label for="name">
                    Ваше имя:
                </label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" />
                <br />
                <!-- class="inputbox required" -->
                <textarea class="WithoutTinymce" cols="50" rows="10" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
            </div> <!-- /article -->
        </form>
    </table>
    {% include "articles.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

I can also paste code from base.html if needed.

EDIT2: minimized code from base.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs">
...
<body id="body-id" onload="loaded()">

<!-- Main -->
<div id="main" class="box">
    <div id="page" class="box">
        <div id="page-in" class="box">
            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="content">
                {% block main %}
                {% endblock %}
                <hr class="noscreen" />
            </div> <!-- /content -->
        </div> <!-- /page-in -->
    </div> <!-- /page -->
</div> <!-- /Main -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems valid, are you sure that you send the form with `POST` method?

Comment: Post your form template source code pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your template you are not making use of `form` passed by the view.

You can update part of your template as (assuming your field names in the form are `first_field` and `second_field`.

```
<form action="/feedback/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="article">
        <label for="name">
            Ваше имя:
        </label>
        <br />
        {{ form.first_field.errors }}
        {{ form.first_field.label_tag }}: {{ form.first_field }}
        <br />
        <!-- class="inputbox required" -->
        {{ form.second_field.errors }}
        {{ form.second_field.label_tag }}: {{ form.second_field }}
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
    </div> <!-- /article -->
</form>
```

For more reference - [Displaying form using template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the form back to the template; and you need to render the form in the template as per jpic's [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template).

The following should render your form errors:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def feedback(request):
    ctx = {}
    ctx['articles'] = Comment.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/thanks')
        else:
            ctx['form'] = form
            return render(request, 'feedback.html', ctx)
    else:
        ctx['form'] = CommentForm()
    return render(request, "feedback.html", ctx)
```

In your template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main %}
    <table>
        <form action="/feedback/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="article">
                {{ form }}
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
            </div> <!-- /article -->
        </form>
    </table>
    {% include "articles.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, your template has this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" />
```

So value attribute of the input tag is always empty.

Same goes for the textarea, which should always render empty:

```
<textarea class="WithoutTinymce" cols="50" rows="10" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
```

Check out the documentation about [rendering a form in a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)